# Adding controls to TableLayoutPanel dynamically during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a TableLayoutPanel starting with two columns and 0 rows. What I need to do is, dynamically adding a row and filling both of the columns with different controls (it will be panels). In Form1 I am creating the TableLayout this way:

```
TableLayoutPanel Table = new TableLayoutPanel();
Table.Location = new Point(10, 40);
Table.Size = new Size(620,100);
Table.AutoSize = true;
Table.Name = "Desk";
Table.ColumnCount = 2;
Table.RowCount = 0;
Table.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
Table.GrowStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
this.Controls.Add(Table);
```

afterwards during runtime I am getting how many rows will I need, and if they will be filled with either a Panel or some Label. It might happen that in the same row left will be Panel, right Label etc..

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
Table.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Type:", Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left, AutoSize = true }, 0, 0);
Table.Controls.Add(new ComboBox { Dock = DockStyle.Fill }, 0, 1);
```

You don't need to define number of rows and columns, they will be added automatically.