# Create Windows Forms controls randomly in a grid?

Tags: c#, forms, random

Is there a way to create Windows Forms controls randomly in a grind style?

Example picture without grid:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh1Hs.png

That or maybe with a like 32x32 grid where the buttons are placed but don't intersect with each other, all cells are filled and maybe there is some space between each cell?

Is there a method I should take a look at?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 possiblities to do what you're asking for:

1- TableLayoutPanel

More infos: [Adding controls to TableLayoutPanel dynamically during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992429/adding-controls-to-tablelayoutpanel-dynamically-during-runtime)

2- Playing with locations

Example:

```
// Start with 2 to have margins in the top/left
int cX = 2;
int cY = 2;

for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
    {
        var btn = new Button();
        btn.Location = new Point(cX, cY);
        btn.Size = new Size(32, 32);
        Controls.Add(btn);
        cX += 34;
    }

    cY += 34;
    cX = 2;
}
```

This will create a 8x8 grid of 32x32 buttons with a space of 2 pixels.